# Override getter/setters created with Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript

I am running into an issue where I am getting an error for properties that I've added to an object via Object.defineProperty.

The error in question.

```
Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

---

Maybe (likely) my design is incorrect and I should be doing something differently. This is what I intend to do with the code below:

- Create an object P via a factory function.
- Pass a config object C to the factory to customise P.
- Store C within P as a private object and get/set the values of C by attaching its properties to P via Object.defineProperty. C may be different for any given P.
- The problem comes when I want to override the default get/set methods for some C.a

I do that as follows:

```
// Create P with a custom (non-default) get method.
let C = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let P = factory.createObject(C);

const customGetA = function(object, property) {
  return function() {
    if(!object[property])
      object[property] = ' ';
    return object[property];
  };
};

P.customgGetMethod('a', customGetA);

// Looking at object in the console reveals the error mentioned above.
```

---

```
let factory = (function() {
  'use strict';

  this.createObject = function(config) {
    const product = {};

    let C = config;

    // Add default getters/setters to the product, referencing the properties of C.
    for (const property in config) {
      Object.defineProperty(product, property, { 
        get: function() { 
          return C[property];
        },
        set: function(value) {
          C[property] = value;
        },
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true
      });
    }

    product.customGetMethod = function(property, callback) {
      // Get the property description.
      let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, property);

      // Assign the custom get method within the callback, binding its values via closure.
      descriptor.get = callback(this, property);

      // Redefine the property with the new get method.
      Object.defineProperty(this, property, descriptor);
    };

    return product;
  };
})();
```

In the end, I want a to be able to pass a custom data object into P and have it remain private, and dynamically generate get/set methods based off of that data so I don't have to get/set boiler plate for *N*-properites * *M*-products. This may not be the best design or implementation, but I am at a loss for how to do it another way.

Any alternatives or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` look for any (infinite) recursion in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter function that `customGetA` creates in `P.customgGetMethod('a', customGetA);` is essentially

```
function() {
  if(!product.a)
    product.a = ' ';
  return product.a;
}
```

When we compare that to the default getter created in the `factory`

```
function() { 
  return C.a;
}
```

we can see that the new one looks up the value in `product`, not the configuration `C`. And looking up a property in `product` evaluates its getter, which is the function we already are in, which recurses until it eventually overflows the stack...

I think you are looking for

```
// Assign the custom get method within the callback, binding its values via closure.
descriptor.get = callback(C, property);
//                        ^
```

to close over the internal configuration object.

Comment: Bah, incredible. Thank you, I missed that in all the nested-function syntax.